# GearMan Backgrounded HTTP Fetch

Tags: php, gearman

I have tasks that get some content from multiple urls in the internet.
When i run my parser with `addTask` - all works good. And all tasks are completed. But when i run `addTaskBackground` that doesn't block `runTasks()` ...Then i can fill queue every time...but many tasks doesn't finish.

What im doing wrong? Maybe i can set timeout for job, if job doesn't finish it starts again?

Comment: Please separate your questions and name the question according to what your question is, not "two questions"

Comment: can you show some code?